# boost::circular_buffer increment begin pointer without use push_back()

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

I just want to increment pointer of boost::circular_buffer container without use of push_back() method. I saw an increment() method but it is in private section. I need write directly to circular buffer, because it is faster than I prepare the data and insert to buffer using push_back().

This is what I have now. It is slow because two copies are involved every time I `push_back()`:

```
struct big_data_block
{
    char data[100000];
}; 

boost::circular_buffer<big_data_block> m_buffer(8);

void FillBuffer() 
{
    big_data_block block;
    ReadFromAnywhere(&block);
    buffer.push_back(block);
}
```

This is what I want, but function like `IncrementBackPointer()` does not exist.

```
void FillBuffer()
{
    ReadFromAnywhere(buffer.end() - 1);
    buffer.IncrementBackPointer();
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code that demonstrates that you're trying to do?

Comment: For future reference you should put the code in the question itself. I've done that for you on this question.

Comment: Thank you, I did it too. But you was faster.

Comment: Your example wouldn't work if the buffer is still empty (i.e. no element to overwrite yet).

Comment: You could just store a pointer to your struct in the circular_buffer?